# Sitecore item:created fields coming up empty

Tags: events

I am writing a `item:created` event. I need to update one of these values, however the .Fields collection comes up empty

Comment: can you add here your code?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `item:added` event like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:added">
        <handler type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.ItemEventHandler, MyAssembly" method="OnItemAdded"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And then in your code:

```
public class ItemEventHandler
{
    protected void OnItemAdded(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        if (args == null)
            return;

        var item = Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var field = item.Fields["TestField"];
        if (field != null)
        {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            field.Value += "ItemEventHandler";
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its strange, all this time I was using the item:created event which was not returning the fields, however the item:saved event seems to be returning the fields, any ideas why?

Comment: I only know that Sitecore itself does not use `item:created`. It uses `item:added` for newly created items. And other events like `item:saved` or `item:moved` for other events. Remember that `item:saved` is called every time item is saved, not only when item is created.

Comment: yeah, so I have two choices, choice 1: use item:created: cannot do much here since I do not have access to the fields.
choice 2: use item:saved.  I can update the fields here, but not the ideal place.

Comment: The odd thing is that if you look way back in their release notes, `item:added` was supposed to be deprecated in favor of `item:created`. Personally, I try not to use either event and instead use the `<addFromTemplate>` item provider pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below details about the events give you a better understanding.

1. **item:added** and **item:created**
   •  These events seem similar, but Sitecore only fires item:added when a user creates an item through the UI.
   •  It fires item:created when code creates items through APIs. 
   •  Use item:added if you only need to trap manual item additions.
2. **item:saved** and **item:saving**
   •  Sitecore fires **item:saved** in either case(**item:added** and **item:created**), Using item:saved lets me put all the logic in a single handler, which fires after create, update, rename, move and potentially other events.
   •  **item:saving** event before committing the change, while it raises the **item:saved** event afterwards. An advantage of using the **item:saving** event as opposed to the **item:saved** event is that you can access the values from the item before the save, and the new values, and can prevent the user from saving their changes.